# Script to rename a .xml file if exists to .xml.old and end script if .old already exists

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a PS logon script to rename a .xml located in %localappdata%\Microsoft\Outlook\16 to .xml.old if it exists but end if the .xml.old is already there; or there is no .xml file.

Answer (score 1):

```
$outlookpath="$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\Outlook\16"

if (test-path $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\Outlook\16\* -include *.xml.old){
write exit
}
else
{
Get-ChildItem -path $outlookpath -Force -Recurse |  where {($_.extension -eq 
'.xml' -and $_ -like '*AutoD*')} |  rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace 
".xml",".xml.old"}
}
```

Comment: also this seems to work but when it runs a second time after creating a .xml.old it outputs the whole script at the prompt

Answer (score 0):

To get you started take a look at:

```
Get-Command -Noun Item
```

and use Get-Help to learn about the commands

```
Get-Help Get-Item -ShowWindow
```

or use the corresponding Web Help

[Get-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item?view=powershell-3.0)

[Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Rename-Item?view=powershell-3.0)